# Decompile swf files and output a log file

Tags: optimization, flash, decompiling

I am looking for a script that will go through  ~75,000 SWF files that we have, will decompile each and find all the Shapes/Elements which size is greater than x.

The output should look smthng like:
SWF Filename  "SWF Path"  "SWF overall Size" "Element Name" "Element Size"....

Does anybody know of a software that might be able to handle that task?

How do decompile scripts work ? would it be easy to write something to handle the above task?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Library for swf parsing: [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf)
- SWF format reference: [version 10](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf)

You'll need to know SWF format basics and shapes/frames definitions. Make an AIR app that will read files and parse them. Surprisingly, ActionScript is probably best way to parse SWF.

Answer (score 0):

There's a .NET based parser called SWFModeller that forms part of the [Swiffotron](https://github.com/izb/Swiffotron) project. It would be able to parse and then inspect the shapes in the SWF.